# changing the shipping on the PDFs

Tags: magento-1.9, payment-methods, pdf

In the backend i change the PO box to say Credit account as we offer a credit account to our customers, However whenever this is the case and we print invoices it still says "PO NUMBER:"
which could be confusing to our customers.

I changed the name in the back end so it shows credit account during checkout. But in the backend and on shipping labels and invoices it still says "PO Number"  how can i change this?

If i am not being clear please just let me know

[image: this is the invoice and i need that to say credit account instead of Purchase Order Number]

[image: What i changed it to in the back end]

Thank you

Comment: Can you please post a screenshot, what you are talking about? For me it sounds like you are mixing shipping and payment?

Comment: The top picture is of the invoice, Where it say "Purchase Order Number" i need it to say "credit account. The second picture is how i changed it in the backend so it says "Credit Account" during the checkout process